# How to center an image in Bootstrap 4 under Ruby on Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

This is my code. But the image isn't center.
Please help! Thanks!

```
    <%= image_tag "avatar.png", size: "120x120", class: "center-block, :alt => "avatar" %>
```

Comment: Hi @ANM , please upvote the answer that you accepted as the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code

```
    <%= image_tag "avatar.png", size: "120x120", class: "mx-auto d-block", :alt => "avatar" %>
```

In `Bootstrap 4`, you could use `mx-auto d-block` to center an image.

Comment: I figured it out later but thank you for your answer!